# Android MotionLayout don't showing animation on real device

Tags: java, android, kotlin, animation

I create animation in MotionLayout Editor in Android Studio 4.0.

I have this animation scene:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
       <KeyFrameSet>
       </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/bt_authorization_login"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ll_login_password_container"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_authorization_forget_password"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ll_login_password_container"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

Animation in MotionLayout Editor work is fine.
[animation in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6uBM.gif)

But when I start it on real device, animation don't showing. I tryed on diferent devices.

How to start animation on device?

Comment: Update this line by <Transition motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd"/>

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to explicitly define button constraints in the end constraint set. You also can use  attribute for code simplicity if you want just to change button visibility in constraint sets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/bt_authorization_login">
            <PropertySet android:visibility="invisible" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/bt_authorization_login">
            <PropertySet android:visibility="visible" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```